# Is there a way to connect a Kinect One sensor (came with Xbox One) to my PC or Mac?

Tags: camera, kinect, sensors, xbox, xbox-one

I have ordered my Kinect one (which comes with Xbox one) online. I understand this uses different connectors but has anyone connected it to the PC/Mac?

Have anyone tried re soldering the wires to a usb connector and trying it on PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has happened!  While there is now [a Kinect based off the Xbox One's version that works with a PC out of the box](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/), hacker Chris Gallizzi managed to create a custom USB (3.0) interface and you can read more about that in the conviniently titled article: [It's Possible to Make the Xbox One Kinect Work for PC, Here's How](http://www.polygon.com/2014/7/18/5915555/its-possible-to-make-the-xbox-one-kinect-work-for-pc-heres-how). It seems you'll still need the SDK which goes for $199.

Thanks to Glen McPherson, you can also get it working on your Mac if you step your way through [this tutorial](http://blog.nelga.com/setup-microsoft-kinect-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/).